# Jquery object vs string problems

Tags: jquery

I deleted my old post as it contained a lot of spam.  And I created a jsfiddle to reproduce the issue I am having.

http://jsfiddle.net/mLxSP/

```
console.clear();
var args = '{ action: downline }';

showObject(args);

showObject({ action: 'downline' });


function showObject(args) {

    console.log(args);        
}
```

How do I pass args as an object?  I'm currently building args into a string dynamically and need to pass it as an object for the function to work correctly.

Comment: You could parse args explicitly to json: `showObject(JSON.parse(args))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not your passing, but rather your declaration that is the problem.  Define args as

```
var args = { action: 'downline' };
```

Comment: Ahh, I'm glad someone understood what I was trying to say.  I don't explain myself the best sometimes.  This worked like a charm, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

args.action, or args[action] will show downline

you can  make also your object like:
args = {};
args.action = 'downline'; etc

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue is.

Your second way is how you pass an object to a function.

This fiddle shows the log: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/mLxSP/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you generated it as valid `JSON`, you could parse the string as json and display that.

```
console.clear();
var args = '{ "action": "downline" }';

showObject($.parseJSON(args));

showObject({ action: 'downline' });


function showObject(args) {

    console.log(args);        
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that is interesting.  I will have to play around with that some.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery "parseJSON" will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var args = $.parseJSON('{"action": "downline" }');
    showObject(args);
    showObject({
        action: 'downline'
    });

    function showObject(args) {
        console.log(args);
    }
});​
```